# How can Rust be told that a thread does not live longer than its caller?

Tags: multithreading, lambda, rust, borrow-checker, borrowing

I have the following code:

```
fn main() {
    let message = "Can't shoot yourself in the foot if you ain't got no gun";
    let t1 = std::thread::spawn(|| {
        println!("{}", message);
    });
    t1.join();
}
```

`rustc` gives me the compilation error:

> closure may outlive the current function, but it borrows `message`, which is owned by the current function

This is wrong since:

1. The function it's referring to here is (I believe) main. The threads will be killed or enter in UB once main is finished executing.
2. The function it's referring to clearly invokes .join() on said thread.

Is the previous code unsafe in any way? If so, why? If not, how can I get the compiler to understand that?

Edit: Yes I am aware I can just move the message in this case, my question is specifically asking how can I pass a reference to it (preferably without having to heap allocate it, similarly to how this code would do it:

```
std::thread([&message]() -> void {/* etc */});
```

(Just to clarify, what I'm actually trying to do is access a thread safe data structure from two threads... other solutions to the problem that don't involve making the copy work would also help).

Edit2: The question this has been marked as a duplicate of is 5 pages long and as such I'd consider it and invalid question in it's own right.

Answer (score 5):

> Is the previous code 'unsafe' in any way ? If so, why ?

The goal of Rust's type-checking and borrow-checking system is to disallow unsafe programs, but that does not mean that all programs that fail to compile are unsafe. In this specific case, your code is not unsafe, but it does not satisfy the type constraints of the functions you are using.

> 2. The function it's referring to clearly invokes .join() on said thread.

But there is nothing from a type-checker standpoint that *requires* the call the `.join`. A type-checking system (on its own) can't enforce that a function has or has not been called on a given object. You could just as easily imagine an example like

```
let message = "Can't shoot yourself in the foot if you ain't got no gun";
let mut handles = vec![];
for i in 0..3 {
    let t1 = std::thread::spawn(|| {
        println!("{} {}", message, i);
    });
    handles.push(t1);
}
for t1 in handles {
    t1.join();
}
```

where a human can tell that each thread is joined before `main` exits. But a typechecker has no way to know that.

> 1. The function it's referring to here is (I believe) main. So presumably those threads will be killed when main exists anyway (and them running after main exists is ub).

From the standpoint of the checkers, `main` is just another function. There is no special knowledge that this specific function can have extra behavior. If this were any other function, the thread would not be auto-killed. Expanding on that, even for `main` there is no guarantee that the child threads will be killed *instantly*. If it takes 5ms for the child threads to be killed, that is still 5ms where the child threads could be accessing the content of a variable that has gone out of scope.

To gain the behavior that you are looking for with this specific snippet (as-is), the lifetime of the closure would have to be tied to the lifetime of the `t1` object, such that the closure was guaranteed to never be used after the handles have been cleaned up. While that is certainly *an* option, it is significantly less flexible in the general case. Because it would be enforced at the type level, there would be no way to opt out of this behavior.

You could consider using [`crossbeam`](https://crates.io/crates/crossbeam), specifically [`crossbeam::scope`'s `.spawn`](https://docs.rs/crossbeam/0.3.0/crossbeam/struct.Scope.html#method.spawn), which enforces this lifetime requirement where the standard library does not, meaning a thread *must* stop execution before the `scope` is finished.

In your specific case, your code works fine as long as you transfer ownership of `message` to the child thread instead of borrowing it from the `main` function, because there is no risk of unsafe code with or without your call to `.join`. Your code works fine if you change

```
let t1 = std::thread::spawn(|| {
```

to

```
let t1 = std::thread::spawn(move || {
```

Comment: I didn't say there's not chance of threads still running when main exit, I said it was ub and as such shouldn't really be relevant to any compiler if it happens, but I get the logic applies by the checker here.

Comment: However for the sake of my sanity I do enjoy sharing state such as container and ro variables between threads. I will try using crossbeam once I get to a normal computer.

Comment: @George: Note that Rust's very reason to exist is to have the compiler eliminate UB. This is what Graydon Hoare was striving for and why Mozilla decided to fund a full-time team to work on it. So, yes, rustc will do its best to prevent UB; it's what it was created for ;)

Comment: @Matthieu MI don't think you understand what I mean here. Let me put it otherwise: If my computer catches fire that's UB, but I as a programmer shouldn't care about it.

Comment: Same with threads lingering after the execution of main, it can happen theoretically, but at that point it's no longer the responsebillity of your program (and even in a program written in Rust, this is still considered UB)

Comment: Also, there's something to say about obfuscation not being a fix to a problem and Rust being horrible when it comes to handling conversions between s/us and 2/4/8bit types (which will result in a lot of UB because there's basically no helper mechanisms in the language for it... especially if you compile cross platform, god help you)

Comment: @George: There is a vast difference between a faulty hardware (the most scary source of "bugs", really) and faulty software. The former needs to be dealt with at hardware level (ECC memory is commonly used in servers, CPU/motherboards monitor temperate/voltage to avoid meltdowns, etc...) and the latter needs to be dealt with at software level (because the hardware blindly executes what you tell it to). I will argue, always, that it is the programmer's responsibility to deal with **all** software issues, and this includes threads running after main ends.

Comment: @George: As for conversions between signed/unsigned and bitwidths; there is no Undefined Behavior here. Actually, since signedness and bitwidths are explicit, there is not even platform specific behavior (unlike C's `int` whose bitwidth is never really known). The only platform specific behavior you'll get is that `isize`/`usize` may have different bitwidths, though both have the same on a given platform, but once again that's not UB. It's perfectly defined, for the current platform.

Comment: programmer's responsibility to deal with all software issues ... There's a difference to be made between user space and kernel space and a difference to be made between your program and another one. You are responsible for preventing bugs in your program, extending to anything past that is an exercise in futility

Comment: SO really isn't the place to debate about language philosophy. Rust tries to prevent undefined behavior where possible, and this is a case where it is absolutely possible. Whether you agree with that design is unrelated to the question of how the language behaves.